# Make OpenSSL accept expired certificates

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

I'm digging through the source code, trying to find a way to get OpenSSL to always accept expired certificates. I can't find the link between the expired errors/alarms and the actual checking code. Can anyone point me in the right direction? (My C isn't great, I'm relying on what can be carried over from C++)

The reason I want to accept expired certificates is because we have a tonne of embedded systems whose certs will expire in a few months (updating not an option because they're either off or in mass storage). The server these connect to knows to only accept these systems so allowing expired certs seemed like the most straightforward solution.

Comment: What kind of changes are you looking to make?  Changes to scripts using `openssl`?  Changes to a custom binary that uses OpenSSL library functions?

Comment: We're using nginx on our server, so I pulled the oppenssl source code and was hoping to force an OK on the expiry check.

Comment: _Who_ exactly rejects the expired certificates? The nginx used as a (reverse) proxy?

Comment: It's nginx compiled with openssl. I think I found what I was looking for inside `ssl/x509_vfy.c`: `static int check_cert_time(...)`. This where the expiry error is set inside libssl, so I'm going to return ok when a expired cert is found. Need to test it now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Make OpenSSL accept expired certificates...

In your verification callback function, you should accept both `X509_V_OK` and `X509_V_ERR_CERT_HAS_EXPIRED`. Maybe something like:

```c
int verify_callback(int preverify, X509_STORE_CTX* x509_ctx)
{
    /* For error codes, see http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/verify.html  */
    int err = X509_STORE_CTX_get_error(x509_ctx);

    if(preverify == 0)
    {
        if(err == X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY)
            fprintf(stdout, "  Error = X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY\n");
        else if(err == X509_V_ERR_CERT_UNTRUSTED)
            fprintf(stdout, "  Error = X509_V_ERR_CERT_UNTRUSTED\n");
        else if(err == X509_V_ERR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN)
            fprintf(stdout, "  Error = X509_V_ERR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN\n");
        else if(err == X509_V_ERR_CERT_NOT_YET_VALID)
            fprintf(stdout, "  Error = X509_V_ERR_CERT_NOT_YET_VALID\n");
        else if(err == X509_V_ERR_CERT_HAS_EXPIRED)
            fprintf(stdout, "  Error = X509_V_ERR_CERT_HAS_EXPIRED\n");
        else if(err == X509_V_OK)
            fprintf(stdout, "  Error = X509_V_OK\n");
        else
            fprintf(stdout, "  Error = %d\n", err);
    }

    if (err == X509_V_OK || err == X509_V_ERR_CERT_HAS_EXPIRED)
        return 1;

    return preverify;
}
```

Another problem with older mobile and IoT gadgets are lack of clocks and/or aux power. You may need to allow `X509_V_ERR_CERT_NOT_YET_VALID` too. You will observe this for a device that powers on and thinks its in the 1990s or 2000s. Older phones without a SIM experience this all the time. I've also observed it in modern [low end] Android phones.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I only saw this after finding another workaround. (I literally commented out the code that set the expired error in `x509_vfy.c`).  

Your solution looks more robust (and nicer!) than mine, however.

Comment: This answer was not enough for my problem. In order for my expired certificate to be accepted, I also had to set the error code with : X509_STORE_CTX_set_error(x509_ctx, X509_V_OK);

Answer (score 2):

**How I solved it:**

The time checks for certificates are in `ssl/x509_vfy.c`:

```
static int check_cert_time(X509_STORE_CTX *ctx, X509 *x)
{
    time_t *ptime;
    int i;

    .
    .
    .

    i = X509_cmp_time(X509_get_notAfter(x), ptime);
    .
    .
    .

    if (i < 0) {
        return 1;
        /* Allow expired certificates!
         *
         * ctx->error = X509_V_ERR_CERT_HAS_EXPIRED;
         * ctx->current_cert = x;
         * if (!ctx->verify_cb(0, ctx))
         *   return 0;
         */
    }

    return 1;
}
```

I just commented out part where is sets the expiration error. Not the best way to do it, I would suggest using [jww's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42277544/4571656) instead. I just thought I should document the solution I used.

This solution means that openssl *can't* detect *any* expired certs, even if `set_verify_cb` changes the callback.

Comment: This is so-called 'monkey patching'.

Answer (score 1):

openssl provides the `-no_check_time` option to "ignore certificate validity time",

```sh
$ openssl verify -CAfile cert1.pem  -CApath ./ cert2.pem  
...
error 10 at 1 depth lookup: certificate has expired
...
error 10 at 0 depth lookup: certificate has expired
error cert2.pem: verification failed

$ openssl verify -no_check_time -CAfile cert1.pem -CApath ./ cert2.pem  
cert2.pem: OK
```