# How to temporarily allow connections with an expired certificate or an old CA certificate in OpenSSL server?

Tags: c++, server, openssl, certificate

My service is using a self-signed certificate.
However, as the ca.crt (ca_old.crt) on server is about to expire,
I have signed a new ca.crt (ca_new.crt) to use it (using the same ca.key, server.key).

ca_old.crt and ca_new.crt use the same ca.key
server_old.crt and server_new.crt use the same server.key

For the new version of clients, they have the ability to update the new ca.crt (ca_new.crt) if verification fails. However, for old versions that do not have the ability to update the ca.crt, So I want to temporarily allow the server to accept connections with expired or old certificates.

There are many embedded devices with ca.crt (ca_old.crt) may not be accepted by server with new ca.crt (ca_new.crt)

I have tried the following methods on my server.

```
int verify_callback(int pre_verify_ok, X509_STORE_CTX *ctx)
{
   // check old CA
   return true;
}

// Set new certificate
SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, "ca_new.crt");
SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(ctx, "server_new.crt");
SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, "server.key");

// Load old CA
STACK_OF(X509_NAME) *ca_list = SSL_load_client_CA_file("ca_old.crt");
SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list(ctx, ca_list);

SSL_CTX_set_verify (ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, verify_callback);
```

I want to check in verify_callback and return true to pass the verification if it is an old CA, and add a flag to limit some behaviors. For new CAs, return pre_verify_ok.

However, my old version clients may have set SSL_VERIFY_PEER, so those which use ca_old.crt or client_old.crt signed by ca_old.crt will not be able to enter the verify_callback.

I understand that this approach may seem strange, but I want to minimize the impact on existing clients. So, for clients connecting with the old ca.crt, I will use a flag to limit their subsequent behavior, such as only allowing them to update to the new version of the client and disallowing other actions. Is this approach feasible?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?  Your server has **one** cert/key pair that it uses to identify itself to clients trying to connect.  You can use the new one, **or** you can use the old, expiring one.  If the new cert/key pair is from a different CA, and the old clients don't trust that CA, they're not going to be able to connect to a server using the new cert/key pair.  Or are you asking about the certs/keys used by the **clients**? Are those expiring?  And you want them to still be able to connect to your server?  If so, do they all have the same cert/key pair?

Comment: See [**Make OpenSSL accept expired certificates**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42272164/make-openssl-accept-expired-certificates) if you're trying to change your *server's* behavior.  You'd also need to add a check to make sure the cert being verified is specifically one that you want to bypass the expiration check for.  You'd need to use `X509_STORE_CTX_get0_cert()` to get that cert from the X509 store context.  Comparing the subject and issuer DN strings to the one(s) you want to ignore the expiration on should be sufficient since they'll still be cryptographically verified.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks for reply, my question is the same as [Make OpenSSL accept expired certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42272164/make-openssl-accept-expired-certificates) , I hope that the server can accept both clients with new ca or the expired certificates, but "verify_callback" is not called.

Comment: If your verify callback is not getting called, the *client* is probably not completing its side of the SSL connection - either because you're using your old server cert and it has expired, or because the client doesn't trust your new server cert.  What cert are you using on your server?  Is it expired?  Do the clients trust it?  If it's expired, or the clients don't trust it, **they won't connect**.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The older ca.crt has not expired yet, but it is about to expire, so I want to load ca_new.crt through SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations when restarting the server next time, and then load the old ca_old.crt through SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list, so that the client can use  ca_new.crt or ca_old .crt can be successfully connected.
In verify_callback, return pre_verify_ok for those clients with ca_new.crt,
return true and marked it expired for those clients with ca_old.crt

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:**

You have to make use of the ex_data technique to store application data into/retrieve application data from the SSL structure as described in the OpenSSL docs example https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html

I've made a small example that is unverified, but expected to work:

```
#include <openssl/ssl.h>

static int mydata_index;
static int verify_callback(int preverify_ok, X509_STORE_CTX *ctx) {
  SSL* ssl = (SSL*)X509_STORE_CTX_get_ex_data(ctx, SSL_get_ex_data_X509_STORE_CTX_idx());
  bool legacy_mode_ = SSL_get_ex_data(ssl, mydata_index);
  if (legacy_mode_) {
    // handle old ca
  }
  return preverify_ok;
}

int main() {
  const SSL_METHOD *method = TLS_server_method();
  SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
  SSL *ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
  bool legacy_;
  mydata_index = SSL_get_ex_new_index(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

  // switch on / off the legacy mode 
  legacy_ = true;
  SSL_set_ex_data(ssl, mydata_index, &legacy_);
  SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, verify_callback);
  return 0;
}
```

Please check the OpenSSL docs for further information.

Comment: You've actually compiled this, without any warnings?  **And** run it successfully? OpenSSL's API is a **C** API, not a C++ API.  The verify callback is a function pointer of the form `extern "C" int (*verify_callback)(int, X509_STORE_CTX *)`

Comment: Good point, this does not work. I've Updated my answer :)

Comment: @Erwin Thanks for help, i tried this method, but 'verify_callback' not called and i don't know why :(

Comment: You can use `openssl s_client` in order to get more information about the ssl handshake. Following example works for google.com, you can change server and port to your server: `openssl s_client -connect google.com:443`